# Commands for execute wps in Android Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, android, wifi-hotspot, wps

My android version is 6.0.1 and i make this work with WI-Fi Protected Setup (WPS) for that i followed some instruction.
I was executed some commands before that i enabled the hotspot in my phone.
The hotspot working fine. But, the commands are not executed properly.​

```
root@sabresd_6dq:/ # **hostapd_cli**
hostapd_cli v2.5-devel-6.0.1
Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.

**Could not connect to hostapd – re-trying**
```

Comment: See the [README-WPS](https://github.com/cucumber-tony/hostap/blob/master/hostapd/README-WPS)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect with the hostapd_cli tool you need to give it the place where to find the socket. Default path to the socket is /var/run/hostapd. On Android 5.1.1 this path is /data/misc/wifi/hostapd

So the command I use is

```
hostapd_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/hostapd all_sta
```

Answer (score -1):

The command is:

```
hostapd_cli  wps_pbc
```

Comment: Could you explain why that's the correct command?

Comment: That thread was created by me only. After some debug I done this WPS Push Button Connect setup. Please check my thread,